# Count all files matching a glob in the current directory and all its subdirectories using BASH scripting

Tags: bash, scripting

I am trying to count all the files matching a specific glob in the current directory and all its subdirectories. An example of this could be finding all files ending with ".txt".

(I must use for loop to match all files in the current directory and another for loop to go through all the subdirectories of the current directory)

```
#!/bin/bash
myglob="$1"
if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
        dir=$1
else
        echo -n Please enter an ending file name:
        read -r  myglob
fi
# echo Directory $dir

numDir=0
numFile=0
for file in ./*; do
#       if [ -d "$file" ]; then
#               echo $file is a FIRST directory
#               let numDir=numDir+1
        if [[ "$file" == *"$myglob" ]]; then
                echo $file is a FIRST file
                let numFile++
        fi
        for file in ./*/*; do
                if [[ "$file" == *"$myglob" ]]; then
                        echo $file is a SECOND file
                        let numFile++
                fi
        done
done
#echo "$dir" contains "$numDir" directories
echo "$dir" contains "$numFile" files
```

Comment: Is this also coursework? Not particularly a problem if so, but it's always helpful to know

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Script to count files matching a pattern in subdirectories](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27389/script-to-count-files-matching-a-pattern-in-subdirectories)

Comment: @roaima yes are you going to help me?

Comment: @Freddy it doesn't help me that, I need to use for loop not while or whatsoever.

Comment: @The_Liner quite possibly, but not tonight as it's just about midnight here and I need some sleep :-)

Comment: Here is almost midnight too, but I need to finish this :(

Comment: So, it's not only coursework you want us to do for you, it's coursework with a deadline, that is a test.

Comment: @waltinator I don't need you to do it for me, I just need help. How do you check if files match a glob, for example ending with .txt?

Comment: .Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Comment: I have used that, but the problem is I do not know how do I check if files match a glob?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be mis-reading the assignment's question.

1. it says **"current directory"**, which is `.`, **not** `~` or `~/linux2/q3`
2. it also says **"and all subdirectories"**.  Given that this appears to be an introductory shell-scripting course, it's extremely unlikely that they expect you to write your own code, in bash, to recurse subdirectories.  That is **not** a task for beginners.

   It almost certainly means "use `find`, the standard tool for recursing subdirectories".
3. It says to use a glob, not to implement your own filename pattern matching.  No matter how well you write your own pattern matching code, it's **NOT** using a glob.

   `find` has a `-name` option which uses globs to match files.

   Note that it also doesn't say "matching a file ending" or file extension.  It says "matching a specific glob" and gives ".txt" as an **example**.  A glob **can** match file extensions, but it can also be used to match a lot more than just that.
4. "write a shell script to do X" (or words like that) does not necessarily mean "write a shell script that doesn't use any external programs, using only built-in commands".  In fact, it certainly does not mean that **unless** it is explicitly stated.

   Calling external programs to do work is what shell scripts do, it's completely normal and expected for shell scripts...especially when using any of the standard unix utilities, like `find` or `wc`.

   `wc` is a standard program which can be used to count the number of characters, lines, and/or words in a file or stdin.  In this case, you only want to count the number of lines, so use  `wc`'s `-l` option.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Count the number of files matching a glob in the current directory
# and all subdirectories.
#
# The glob can be specified on the command line, in which case it
# MUST be quoted or escaped to prevent the shell from expanding it.
# e.g. use '*.txt' or \*.txt, not just *.txt.
#
# if the glob is not specified on the command line, the script prompts
# for a glob until one is provided.

myglob="$1"

while [ -z "$myglob" ] ; do
  read -p 'Enter a glob: ' myglob
done

numfiles=$(find . -type f -name "$myglob" | wc -l)
echo $numfiles
```

If there is any chance that any of the filenames in the current directory have newlines (i.e. `LF` characters) in them (which **is** a valid character in unix filenames), then use `NUL` as the filename separator instead of `LF`:

```bash
numfiles=$(find . -type f -name "$myglob" -print0 |
             awk -v RS='\0' '{count++}; END {print count}')
```

Instead of using `wc -l`, this uses an `awk` script to count the NUL-separated filenames.

Or, as Stéphane Chazelas pointed out in a comment, you can do this with just `find` and `grep`:

```bash
numfiles=$(find .//. -type f -name "$myglob" | grep -c //)
```

The `.//.` starting-directory argument causes `find` to output filenames prefixed with `.//`.  Since it's impossible for `//` to appear in a filename from `find`, you can use `grep -c //` to count the files.  The `.//` only appears in a filename once, so this works whether there are newlines in the filename or not.

BTW, it is good shell programming practice to **always** account for the possibility of newlines and other problematic characters (e.g. spaces, tabs, semi-colons, ampersands, etc) in filenames, even when you think it's probably not going to be an issue.  It's one of the reasons why you should always double-quote your variables when you use them.  And the reason why using NUL as a filename separator is better, more reliable, and safer than just using LF.

If you explain the reasoning behind using NUL as the separator instead of newline, that's probably worth extra marks.

---

#### Update

Even if you are required to use two for loops rather than `find`, you still shouldn't do your own pattern matching. Your code is not using globs to match files - it's using your own custom pattern matching code.  That's not the same thing, not even close.

Here's an example using two for loops that actually uses globs to count matching files.  I've added notes under each loop to explain them, but in a script you'd just run one loop after the other.

Loop 1 for current directory:

```bash
for f in $myglob; do
  [ -f "$f" ] && let numFile++
done
```

This `for` loop is an example of one of the very few instances where you **don't** want to quote `$myglob` when you use it because you **want** the shell to expand the glob.

In almost all other cases, you do not want the shell to expand variables on a command line, so you **must** enclose them in double-quotes: `"$myglob"` rather than just `$myglob`.   Also, while not relevant for this script, you should still double-quote array variables like `"${array[@]}"` even when you want them to be expanded, because you want each individual element of the array to be treated as one "word".

Anyway, this uses `[ -f "$f" ]` to test if "$f" exists and is a regular file, so that it only counts files, not directories (or anything else, like symlinks or named pipes aka fifos).   This does the same thing as using `find`'s `-type f` option.

If you wanted to count directories in `./` instead of (or as well as) files, you would use:

```bash
[ -d "$f" ] && let numDir++
```

Loop 2 for immediate subdirectories:

```bash
for f in */$myglob ; do
  [ -f "$f" ] && let numFile++
done
```

This is almost identical to the first for loop, except it's iterating over `*/$myglob` instead of just `$myglob`.

All together, that's something like:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# comments deleted, same as version using find above.

myglob="$1"

while [ -z "$myglob" ] ; do
  read -p 'Enter a glob: ' myglob
done

for f in $myglob; do
  [ -f "$f" ] && let numFile++
done

for f in */$myglob ; do
  [ -f "$f" ] && let numFile++
done

echo "$(pwd)/ and $(pwd)/*/ combined contain $numFile files matching '$myglob'"
```

Unlike the `find` version, these loops will only count files in the current directory and directories immediately below it.  It won't recurse any deeper into sub-subdirectories, etc.

This is probably what you want, as far as I can tell from reading your question.

You can limit the recursion depth in `find` using the `-maxdepth` option.   e.g. `find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -name "$myglob"`.

Comment: You could do `find ... -printf . | wc -c` to count `find` result. Then you have no issues with newline and don't need `--files0-from=-`

Comment: yeah, but why tell a beginner to use an obscure trick when `wc -l` is obvious, standard, and easily understood.

Comment: It's a trick, but imo not obscure. For me `--files0-from=-` is the more obscure trick, and I would have to look it up every time. But sure, it's a matter of choice :-) Your version is also valid.

Comment: also, `printf` is as non-standard for `find` as `--files0-from` is for `wc`.  It's still a GNU-ism.

Comment: That's true of course :-)

Comment: BTW, I have NFI why they didn't just use `-0` or `-z` for `wc`, like every other program with an option for NUL-separated input.   Mind-boggling, but that's what they chose.

Comment: @The_Liner   extra bonus points: it is possible to count how many command-line arguments were provided.  You could use this to print an error message & exit if it's not zero or exactly one.  Or you could use it in a loop to handle more than one argument.   I'll leave these things for you to do if you want, because they're good learning exercises.

Comment: @pLumo actually, you were right.   `--files0-from=-` expects a list of file names, which `wc` then processes the same as if those filenames were on the command line (to avoid using xargs which could mess up the total if there are more filenames than would fit in one command line).  It is **not** the same as `-0` or `-z`.    GNU `wc` didn't bother implementing that....I'll use awk instead.

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying to help me, but I must use two for loops, one to find matching files in the current directory and another to iterate in the subdirectories as is shown in my code.

Comment: Even if required to use two `for` loops, you still shouldn't do your own pattern matching.  They're **not** globs - they're your own custom pattern matching code.   e.g. two for loops, one for current directory:  `for f in $myglob; do [ -f "$f" ] && let numFile++ ; done`, and one for immediate subdirectories: `for f in */$myglob ; do [ -f "$f" ] && let numFile++ ; done`

Comment: See also `find .//. ... | grep -c //` to count file paths instead of lines in file paths.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas nice. i like that better than `find ... -printf . | wc -c`.

Comment: I don't understand why I have this error: temp.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `$'do\r''
'emp.sh: line 7: `for f in $myglob; do

Comment: @The_Liner `\r` is a carriage-return character (CR).  Unix uses line-feeds (LF, aka NL aka newline), `\n` only as end-of-line in a text file.  Windows uses CR followed by LF.  My guess is you edited the file on a Windows machine.   You can convert using `dos2unix` or similar programs or with `perl -i -p -e 's/\r\n/\n/' filename` if you don't have that installed.   or edit with vim and run `:set fileformat=unix` and `:x` to save the file and exit.

Answer (score 0):

The way to expand the `*.txt` in the current directory and count the number of names that matched is to do

```bsh
set -- ./*.txt
```

This sets the positional parameters (`$1`, `$2`, etc.) to the names matching the globbing pattern.  If the `nullglob` shell option is set in the `bash` shell, this would be an empty list if there are no matches, otherwise the list would contain the unexpanded pattern itself.  If the `dotglob` shell option is set in the `bash` shell, the list would include hidden names as well, if there are any that matches the pattern (`*` does not otherwise match hidden names).

The length of the list of positional parameters is `$#`.

This means that the following is a short `bash` script that counts and reports how many (possibly hidden) names matches `*.txt` in the current directory.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s dotglob nullglob
set -- ./*.txt

printf 'There are %d names matching ./*.txt here\n' "$#"
```

If we enable the `globstar` shell option, we gain access to `**`, which matches down into subdirectories.  We could then easily extend our script above to search recursively under the current directory and below:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s dotglob nullglob globstar
set -- ./**/*.txt

printf 'There are %d names matching ./**/*.txt here\n' "$#"
```

You could obviously store the matching names in a named array if you so wish:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s dotglob nullglob globstar
names=( ./**/*.txt )

printf 'There are %d names matching ./**/*.txt here\n' "${#names[@]}"
```

Would you want to print the matching names in a single column, you may do so with

```bsh
printf '%s\n' "$@"
```

or, if you are using a named array in `bash`,

```bsh
printf '%s\n' "${names[@]}"
```

Would you need to count only regular files, then you obviously need to iterate over the names matching the glob:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob dotglob globstar

regular_files=()

for pathname in ./**/*.txt; do
    if [ -f "$pathname" ] && [ ! -L "$pathname" ]; then
        regular_files+=( "$pathname" )
    fi
done

printf 'There are %d regular files matching ./**/*.txt\n' "${#regular_files[@]}"
```

The `-L` test used above is *true* if the given pathname is a symbolic link, so the combination of tests used here ensures that we only count actual regular files, and no symbolic link to a regular file.

Comment: Beware that even with bash 5.1, if the current directory contains symlinks to directories, it will also count the text files in the directories they point to (not recursively, and not in targets of symlinks at deeper levels...). Would be better to zsh (where recursive globbing comes from and doesn't have this kind of issue and has glob qualifiers and where you can also disable sorting and which hash much more advanced globs). `() { echo there are $# files; } **/*.txt(ND.oN)`